# Numerical method to calculate the shortest distance between two points on a cone?

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

Are there any numerical methods to calculate the shortest distance between two points along the surface of a cone? The motivation is to calculate the distance between two sensors on the surface of a structure. One of the sections of this structure would have a conical shape (although not a full cone; it is a truncated cone). I know that a path between two points along a general surface is called a geodesic, and I've been able to find numerical methods for geodesic distance on other kinds of shapes, but I've had trouble finding something similar for a cone.

The goal is to implement such a method in code (Python), and of course the ideal situation would be if there is an existing library that already has an implementation. I can ask a follow-up question that is more focused on the programming part of this on another StackExchange site, but for now I'm asking the question here because I haven't been able to find sufficient information on what kind of methods are available and what they are called.

Comment: Just lookup "Geodesics in a cone".

Comment: I have done several searches about the topic. I'm asking this question here because I haven't found information for a numerical method that could be implemented in code.

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly, the cones you're considering are flat - you can form them by folding a flat piece of paper. This should solve your problem, but I couldn't say more without more context.

Comment: @tangology The cone is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$... You can obtain a geodesic just by mapping two point onto the plane, drawing a straight line between them and mapping back onto the cone.

Answer (score 1):

The Mapping $F:U\to C$, with $U=\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2: u >  0\}$, given by
$$
F(u,v)=(u \sin \alpha \cos v, u \sin \alpha \sin v, u \cos \alpha)
$$
is an isometry between the half space and the cone. If you are given two points on the cone, $P_1 = F(u_1,v_1)$ and $P_2=F(u_2,v_2)$, the distance between them is the same as in the $(u,v)$ plane, i.e. $d = \sqrt{(u_1-u_2)^2+(u_2-v_2)^2}$. If, as an input, you are given the cartesian coordinates of the points, you just need to start by computing the $(u,v)$ coordinates by solving for each point the system
$$
\begin{cases}
u \sin \alpha \cos v = x\\ u \sin \alpha\sin v = y\\ u \cos \alpha = z
\end{cases}.
$$

You can get exact formulas foir this, there is no need for numerics (if yiou disregard roundoff errors).